# Joomla 2.5.27-31: Can't edit article any more

Tags: web, joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5, edit

My Joomla installation just got updated (automatically) from 2.5.6-3 to 2.5.27-31 and all the formatting of the frontpage got lost. Trying to re-format it, I discovered (using TinyMCE editor), that I can format it, but once I hit "Save", the whole text's formatting gets reset to the previous state.

I'm using the beez5 theme, and aside from some modules and plug-ins (i.e. Facebook and Twitter integration), the installation is pretty much stock.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try to change editor

Comment: Does not work - switched to JCE editor and no change.

Comment: I had same problem with wordpress. And descoverd that problem was qtranslate. If you have multi languge site check translte component.